# How to add comma-separated string value to an 'IN' clause as an item list in SQL using sub select query?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have `columnA` of data type `VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)` in an Oracle database `tableA`. `columnA` has comma-separated values as shown below (shows one record of the `columnA` for `id=1`).

[image: one record]

I need to insert the record as separate list of values into an `IN` clause using a sub select query.

Below is what I tried.

```
... IN (SELECT tableA.columnA FROM tableA WHERE tableA.id = '1')
```

Expected:

```
... IN (2222222226,2222222224,2222222227)
```

But I don't get the expected result. Please suggest a way for this.

Comment: A comma separated string is not the same as separate values in `in` clause. You're essentially doing `... IN ('2222222226,2222222224,2222222227')`

Comment: You will need to parse the string and split it into multiple values - which you can do in your subquery. There are lots of questions about how to tokenize a comma-separated string.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
FROM other_table
WHERE columnA IN (
    SELECT regexp_substr(columnA, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    FROM tableA
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(columnA, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
)
```

Here in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/58728/4).